# C# returning all files located in a directory which has folders in it

Tags: c#, file, directory, getfiles

How can I retrieve all the files in a directory that has files, sub-folders, and files in that folders.

**NOTE:** The folder/files is not constant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use  [Directory.GetFiles(path)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=net-5.0) and [Directory.GetDirectories(path)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getdirectories?view=net-5.0)

```
static void ScanDir(string path, int spaces = 0)
{
    var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
    foreach (var file in files)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < spaces; i++)
            Console.Write(" "); // Just for styling

        Console.WriteLine(file);
    }

    var dirs = Directory.GetDirectories(path);
    foreach (var dir in dirs)
    {
        ScanDir(dir, spaces + 4);
    }
}


static void Main()
{
    ScanDir("C:\\path\\to");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`DirectoryInfo.GetFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles?view=net-5.0) method with the [`RecurseSubdirectories`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.enumerationoptions.recursesubdirectories?view=net-5.0) option.

```
using System.IO;

FileInfo[] files 
    = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files")
    .GetFiles("*", new EnumerationOptions { RecurseSubdirectories = true });
```

If you don't need the full list of files, it may be faster to enumerate the directory's contents.

```
using System.IO;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

var directory = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Program Files");
IEnumerable<FileInfo> files 
    = from file in directory.EnumerateFiles("*", new EnumerationOptions { RecurseSubdirectories = true })
      where file.Name = "target.txt"
      select file;

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    //...
}
```